# Kubernetes Nginx-Ingress oauth_proxy how to pass information/token to service

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am running a Kubernetes Cluster with an Nginx-ingress fronting couple of web apps. Because Nginx doesn't support SSO/OIDC by default, I use an oauth_proxy for authentication.

Everything is working, only verified users are able to access the web pages.

Is it possible to pass or request information from the Identity Provider to the client?

#### Edit

I already use oauth2_proxy (https://github.com/pusher/oauth2_proxy) with Azure AD. The issue is that I need all user details from the IP.

Logs from my oauth2_proxy:

```
$ kubectl logs oauth2-proxy-7ddc97f9d5-ckm29
[oauthproxy.go:846] Error loading cookied session: Cookie "_oauth2_proxy" not present
...
[requests.go:25] 200 GET https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6 {
  "odata.metadata":"https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/$metadata#directoryObjects/@Element",
  "odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
  "objectType":"User", 
  ... ,
  "sipProxyAddress":"nico.schuck@example.com",
  "streetAddress":"my stree",
  "surname":"Schuck",
  "telephoneNumber":55512345,
  "usageLocation":"DE",
  "userType":"Member"
}
165.xxx.xxx.214 - nico.schuck@example.com [2020/01/17 11:22:02] [AuthSuccess] Authenticated via OAuth2: Session{email:nico.schuck@example.com user: token:true id_token:true created:2020-01-17 11:22:02.28839851 +0000 UTC m=+181.592452463 expires:2020-01-17 12:22:02 +0000 UTC refresh_token:true}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider oauth2_proxy which works well with nginx ingress for SSO. Follow the below link

https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy

You should be using below configuration in your Ingress Rule

```
metadata:
  name: application
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Maybe I pronounced it wrong. I already use oauth2_proxy because Nginx doesn't support SSO by default! I want to know how I get the user details from oauth2_proxy

Comment: I'm very grateful for your help. The oauth2_proxy is already working and I see the email of the user under /oauth2/userinfo. But how I can get more details like the name (which is provided by the IP)

Comment: look at vouch-proxy to see if it fits your requirement --> https://github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy

Comment: I will check. does it mean pusher/oauth2_proxy does not support providing user details? ANd isn't it possible to contact that IP by the oauth_proxy?